# MySQL in one table but not in other table with specific ID - query gives too many results?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: `uri` and `pages`. The `uri` contains the url of the page and the url of the page is also stored as slug in `pages`.

Because I can have `forwarders` that are not connected to the `page` but are stored in the `uri` table, I need a query to extract these 'not-connected-to-a-page' url's from the database.

I tried using the following query for that:

```
SELECT uri.* 
FROM uri
LEFT JOIN pages 
ON uri.f_site_id = pages.f_site_id
WHERE uri.f_site_id = '2' // <-- Site id here
AND pages.slug IS NULL
```

The problem is that there must be like 30 results, and there are 2112 results... On which every results returns a lot of times!
It does a lot more than I am expecting, what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the ones that are *not* connect to pages, then you need to express this in the query:

```
SELECT uri.* 
FROM uri LEFT JOIN
     pages 
     ON uri.f_site_id = pages.f_site_id
WHERE uri.f_site_id = '2' AND // <-- Site id here
      pages.f_site_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: I am so sorry, I forgot to add that last line into my question. I get the 2112 results with the part, AND pages.slug IS NULL, added to the query